# Convert a long to a string with the guarantee no heap memory used

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to convert a long to a string in a memory allocator so I need to avoid using heap memory.

I thought about using `sprintf` but somewhere down the line it uses heap memory as in the call stack that I am getting. i.e. `LocaleUpdate`. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Can you implement your own (simplified) `itoa()` on a stack allocated fixed size array?

Comment: How about something like `strtok` (it uses static local storage) which returns next digit on subsequent calls. You can write it such that returns `\0` when number reduces to zero. The only problem is multiple calls required...

Comment: If that's the part you're currently missing: `sizeof(long)*CHAR_BIT` **/** `(log(10)/log(2))` **<** `sizeof(long)*CHAR_BIT / 3` is an upper bound for the length of the resulting string (+1 for the 0-terminator).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/**
 * Convert a long to a string in a provided buffer.
 *
 * @param n      The long to convert to a string
 * @param s      The buffer to build the string in. Should be
 *               long enough to hold as big a string as a
 *               negative long with a terminating zero can be.
 *
 * @return A pointer to the result of the conversion.
 */
char* itoaish(long n, char* s)
{
    int negative = 0;
    char* p = &s[11];
    if(0 > n)
    {
        negative = 1;
        n = -n;
    }
    *p = 0;
    if(!n)
    {
        *--p = '0';
    }
    while(n)
    {
        *--p = '0' + n % 10;
        n /= 10;
    }
    if(negative)
    {
        *--p = '-';
    }
    return p;
}

main()
{
    long n = -1234567890;
    char s[12];
    char* p = itoaish(n,s);
    printf("%s",p);
}
```